# How to convert byte array containing float values to a double array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to convert a byte array containing floats(4 bytes as a float) into a double array in the fastest way possible so I'm using blockcopy as internet suggested it. But , it seems like the values were not correct after the conversion into double can somebody help with!

```
public static void Test()
        {
            var floatArray = new float[] { 123.45f, 123f, 45f, 1.2f, 34.5f };
            // create a byte array and copy the floats into it...
            var byteArray = new byte[floatArray.Length * sizeof(float)];



            Buffer.BlockCopy(floatArray, 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

            // create a double array and copy the bytes into it...
            var doubleArray = new double[byteArray.Length / 4];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(byteArray, 0, doubleArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // do we have the same sequence of floats that we started with?
            foreach(var i in doubleArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                // outputs -->   387028163194470.4 ,   0.02500000981399353 ,    5.474008307E-315 ,   0 ,   0
            }
        }
```

Comment: BlockCopy() merely copies bytes, it doesn't try to convert them.  But conversion is what you need, the internal representation of a [float value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_standard:_binary32) is very different from a [double value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need speed, you're not going to get faster than this...

```
public static void Test()
{
    float val = 1024.24f;
    unsafe
    {
        // byte buffer
        Span<byte> bytes = stackalloc byte[Unsafe.SizeOf<double>()];

        // float to bytes
        fixed (byte* ptr = bytes) *((float*)ptr) = val;

        // bytes to double
        double dbl = default;
        fixed (byte* ptr = bytes) dbl = *((float*)ptr);
        
        // result
        Console.Write(dbl);
        
        //output: 1024.239990234375d == 1024.24f
    }   
}
```

See instructions below to understand what's happening on here - . The bytes are loaded onto the stack as a Float32, top of stack is converted to Float64, and then it's popped off the stack into into the local `double` at index 2...

[image: MSIL]

Comment: How does that work since `float` and `double` have different binary representations? Where exactly is the conversion happening?  Can you elaborate a bit more on your code?

Comment: They're identical as all single values can be represented by double.  Both conform to IEEE 754 double just has more possible digits.  The `1024.24F` value that we start out with is actually `1024.239990234375`.  Go here and plug in the original value in the top box...https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point

Comment: @JohnAlexiou - sorry - i misread your question.  see above for the explanation i added.  the value goes from binary -> Float32 -> Float64

Comment: Why would this be faster than conversion with `(double)x` ? Wouldn't this translate to `conv.r8` IL code also?

Comment: By `x` are you referring to the origin `float` value? The OP asked how to convert a "byte array containing float" to double.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Copy()` can convert from `float` to `double`.

Here is an example

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float[] f_arr = new float[] { 1.1111f, 22.22f, 333.3f };

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", f_arr));

        double[] d_arr = new double[f_arr.Length];

        Array.Copy(f_arr, d_arr, f_arr.Length);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", d_arr));
    }
}
```

with output:

```
1.1111, 22.22, 333.3
1.1110999584198, 22.2199993133545, 333.299987792969
```

as you can see the precision is crap (since the 24 bit mantissa of `float` is assigned to the 53 bit mantissa of `double`). But it will do the trick without worrying about using byte arrays, and `Buffer.Copy()`.

Comment: The precision isn't crap, double is just more precise.  Try testing equality - `2.22f == 22.2199993133544921875d`

Comment: Wouldn't `22.22f == 22.2199999999999997` ?

Comment: Yes, we're saying the same thing.  My brain just processed what you wrote in the inverse direction...crap -> double :)